# how to find if a word contains a permutation of a pattern characters?

Tags: regex, string, algorithm

i have a pattern of length <=100 ,and a set of words <20 i wanna find the number of  words that contains a permutation of the pattern characters for example if the pattern was "cat" and the set of words was "ttact tract tattc" the output should be two.
ttact: matches because it contains tac
tract: matches because it contains act
tattc: dose not match match

here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String pattern="cat";
 char []p=pattern.toCharArray();
 Arrays.sort(p);
String sen="ttact tract tattc";
for (char c : p)
    System.out.println(c);
String [] words=sen.split(" ");

if (pattern.length()==1)
{
    String [] len=sen.split(pattern);
}
else 
{
    int count=0;
for (String word :words)
{
    String found="";

  for (int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
  {
      if (pattern.indexOf(word.charAt(i))!=-1)
      {
        found+=word.charAt(i);
        if (found.length()==pattern.length())
        {
            char f [] = found.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(f);
            if (Arrays.equals(f, p))
            {
            count++;
            found="";
            }
            else
                found="";

        }


      }
      else
        {
            found="";
        }


  }


}
 System.out.println(count);


}}}
```

Comment: Please be more precise in the description what you want to achieve. The word `tract` also contains a permutation of `cat` so it should count as well.

Comment: Provide more examples and clarify your logic.

Comment: yes it dose count , but tattc doesn't ;because it doesn't contain consecutive permutation of cat

Comment: that was only the idea here is the real question if any1 is  intrested http://acm.hnu.cn/online/?action=problem&type=show&id=12881

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any permutation of the characters in the pattern must have exactly the same length as the pattern. You could investigate all the substrings of a word with the same length as the pattern and check for each substring if it is a permutation of the pattern (for example by sorting the letters). Repeat for each word and count the matches.

Comment: i know the problem is that it will be very expensive time wise take a look at the link in the question comments.

Comment: looked at my own question for a sec , implemented it and it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can split the solution into 2 steps

1- find all the permutations of the word you have ( cat => cat, cta , act, atc, tca, tac )
you can refer to this [Finding all permutation of words in a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635868/finding-all-permutation-of-words-in-a-sentence)

2- find the number of occurrence of each of the result in the string you have
you can use linq, for example

```
var permutations=PermuteWords(input); // this function you should get it from the link above
var words = sen.Split(' '); //you will split your sentence into array of words
var count=0; // this variable will store all the occurrences and if you want to get the words that occurred, you can use list to store them
foreach(var p in permutations)
{
     count+=(from w in words
             where permutations.Contains(w)
             select w).Count();
}
```

hope this will help you

if you still have any question, don't hesitate to mention it, and if it helped you, please mark it as answer.

Comment: Given that the pattern can have up to 100 characters this is not practical.

Comment: you know the pattern cat is only three chars long , but what if the pattern was of length 100 ? i specified this in the question